# format columns on data frame in r

Tags: r, format, apply

> I want to format certain columns of a data frame changing decimal mark and number of decimal positions

```
a <- c(3.412324463,3.2452364)
b <- c(2.2342,4.234234)
c <- data.frame(A=a, B=b)
```

> I can do it column by column but would rather apply it to various columns, also I can not find number of decimals. "digits=2" gives me only to digits, including decimal part

```
c$A <- format(c$A, decimal.mark = ",",digits = 2)
```

Comment: The use of `c` as object name is negligent, because it is the heavily used function for concatenate. Try to emember to check with e.g. `?c` if an object name is not already occupied by something important.

Comment: To display always two decimals (that are not 0) `format(round(3.412324463, 2), decimal.mark = ",")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better not to use function names (`c`) to name objects.  To apply the `format` to all the columns

```
c[] <- lapply(c, format, decimal.mark = ",", digits = 2)
```

Or with `formatC`

```
c[] <- lapply(c, formatC, decimal.mark =",", format = "f", digits = 2)
```

If we need to apply to selected multiple columns, i.e. columns 1 to 3 and 7:10

```
j1 <- c(1:3, 7:10)
c[j1] <- lapply(c[j1, formatC, decimal.mark =",", format = "f", digits = 2)
```

Or another option with `sprintf`

```
c[] <- lapply(c, function(x) sub(".", ",", sprintf("%0.2f", x), fixed = TRUE))
```

Comment: How to apply only to the second column? and I need 2 decimals, not 2 digits.thanks!

Comment: @lucas You can use the second option with `sprintf`, If you need to apply only single column, use the same method you had `c$B` or by position `c[[2]] <- format(c[[2]], ..`

Comment: thanls. I need to do apply it to plenty of different columns on my real problem. So I should specify  which columns to apply it to. appreciate your help :)

Comment: @lucas You can also do this with `formatC` `formatC(c[[2]], format = "f", digits = 2, decimal.mark = ",")#
[1] "2,23" "4,23"`

Comment: @lucas For multiple columns and not the entire column, then speciffy the index i.e. suppose you need to do this for columns 1:3 and 7:10, `c[c(1:3, 7:10)] <- lapply(c[c(1:3, 7:10)], formatC, decimal.mark =",", format = "f", digits = 2)` Note that `c` as a function I have to use here

Answer (score 1):

There is also a package called [fmtr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=fmtr) designed specifically for this situation.  It lets you control the formatting for each column independently.  There are two main functions `fapply()` and `fdata()`.

`fapply()` applies a format to a vector or single column.  Like this:

```
a <- c(3.412324463,3.2452364)
b <- c(2.2342,4.234234)
c1 <- data.frame(A=a, B=b)
c2 <- c1

c2$A <- fapply(c2$A, "%.3f")
c2$B <- fapply(c2$B, "%.4f")

c2

#       A      B
# 1 3.412 2.2342
# 2 3.245 4.2342
```

`fdata()` applies formats to an entire data frame.  All you have to do is assign the format to the `format` attribute of the column, and then call of the `fdata()` function on the data frame. `fdata()` will apply all the formats assigned, and leave any unformatted columns alone:

```
c3 <- c1

# Assign formats
attr(c3$A, "format") <- "%.1f"
attr(c3$B, "format") <- "%.2f"

# Apply formats
fdata(c3)

#     A    B
# 1 3.4 2.23
# 2 3.2 4.23
```

There is also a `formats()` function that allows you to more easily assign the format attributes to different columns.  You just create a named list, where each name corresponds to the column you want to assign formats to.  Then you can call the `fdata()` function like above:

```
c4 <- c1

# Assign formats
formats(c4) <- list(A = "%.2f",
                    B = "%.1f")
# Apply formats
fdata(c4)

#      A   B
# 1 3.41 2.2
# 2 3.25 4.2
```